# Decimals in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, decimal, rounding

I spent a few days with a problem that is not how to solve it. I'm doing a report in Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2010 and it works correctly so far all I have to show decimals, which magically always rounded to the nearest integer, ie if the number is 13.80 rounded to the 14, when I want to leave 13.80.

The stored procedure that retrieves the database retrieves the data correctly. The report and created a variable called "normal" to have a little formula created, that is:

```
if {pr_recuperar_apuntes_trabajador2; 1.tipo_apunte} = '3 'then

            {pr_recuperar_apuntes_trabajador2; 1.Quantity};
```

This makes all that proves is that the "tipo_apunte" is the number 3 to show the amount, if it shows nothing. I imagine that the problem is in the formula, but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Right click the object and select **Format Object**. Then click on **Customize** Button in the window which you get. Then you can see the following dialog box.
[image: rounding decimal]
In the above window select the rounding option as 0.01 and Decimals as 1.00 (just for example, u can adjust even more). So that your value will not be rounded for 2 digits. Your value will remain as 13.80

Answer (score 3):

Select the field.
Click the 'Increase Decimals' button twice.

[image]